# Styling Error: React Native not Rendering Top Tab Navbar Components when using ScrollView

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-tab-view

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bwc1.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkhbh.jpg)

Hello developers, I'm coding an application using react native, and the profile screen must contain a small design on top of a Tab Navbar, (as showing in the picture).

The problem is that the TopTabNavbar is not rendering its route components when I try to wrap the wode within a ScrollView (First image with the full display of the design on top of the TabView), but when I remove ScrollView and use SafeAreaView or SafeAreaProvider, or even View with flex:1 style, it renders its components perfectly well. I don't know what the problem is, so I'll show you the code.

```js
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, useWindowDimensions, FlatList} from 'react-native'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { SafeAreaProvider, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
import { COLORS, FONTS, SIZES } from '../../constants/theme'
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import  Constants  from 'expo-constants'
import MainHeader from '../../components/MainHeader'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import Header from '../../components/Header'
import images from '../../constants/images'
import { imagesDataURL } from '../../constants/data'
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker"
//   import {user} from '../search/user'
import UserTabs from '../../navigation/UserTabs';
import { SceneMap, TabBar, TabView } from "react-native-tab-view";
import EventHistory from './EventHistory'
import PersonalInfo from './PersonalInfo'
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native'



const cover =require('../../assets/images/splash.png')
const user=[{
    fullname:"Rayan Henkins",
    title:"Event Organizer",
    location:"Paris, France",
    eventsAchieved:10,
    src: require('../../assets/images/gordon.jpg')}]

const height= Dimensions.get('window').height
const marginTop= Constants.statusBarHeight

const renderScene = ({ route }) => {
    switch (route.key) {
      case 'first':
        return <EventHistory />;
      case 'second':
        return <PersonalInfo />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };


export default function UserDesign(){
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage]=useState(null)
    const handleImageSelection = async () =>{
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes:ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing:true,
            aspect:[4,4],
            quality:1
        }); console.log(result);
        if(!result.canceled){
            setSelectedImage(result.assets[0].uri)
        }
    }
    const layout = useWindowDimensions();
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    
    const [routes] = useState([
        { key: "first", title: "Agenda" },
        { key: "second", title: "Personal Info" },
      ]);
    
      const renderTabBar = (props) => (
        <TabBar
          {...props}
          indicatorStyle={{
            height: 5,
            borderRadius: 5,
            backgroundColor: COLORS.green,
          }}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
            height: 44,
          }}
          renderLabel={({ focused, route }) => (
            <Text style={[{ color: focused ? COLORS.black : COLORS.gray,textTransform:'capitalize',fontWeight:'bold' }]}>
              {route.title}
            </Text>
          )}
        />
      );

      console.log('index:', index);
      console.log('routes:', routes);
    return(

       <View style={styles.container}>
      
         <MainHeader title="Hadarli" />
         <Header />
         
            <StatusBar backgroundColor={COLORS.lightWhite} />
            <SafeAreaProvider style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={styles.mediaContainer}>
            <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
            <Image
                source={images.cover}
                resizeMode='cover'
                style={styles.imageStyle}
            />
            </View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.profilePicBorderContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={handleImageSelection}
            >
                <Image 
                    source={{uri:selectedImage}}
                    resizeMode='contain'
                    style={styles.profileImage}
                />
                <View style={styles.iconImage}>
                    <Ionicons 
                    name="camera-outline"
                    size={32}
                    color={COLORS.green}
                    />
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text
                    style={styles.nameStyle}
                >{user[0].fullname}</Text>
                <Text
                style={styles.titleStyle}
                >{user[0].title}</Text>
                <View style={styles.locationStyle}>
                    <Ionicons
                        name={"location-outline"} size={24} color={COLORS.green}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.locationTextStyle}>{user[0].location}</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.activityCardContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.activityCard}>
                        <Text style={styles.activityCardNumber}>{user[0].eventsAchieved}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.activityCardText}>Events</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>


                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonPress}>
                            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                                Contact
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>

          
            <View style={{ flex: 1, marginHorizontal: 22, marginTop: 20 }}>
                <TabView
                navigationState={{ index, routes }}
                renderScene={renderScene}
                onIndexChange={setIndex}
                initialLayout={{ width: layout.width }}
                renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
                />
      </View>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
   
</View>     
)
           

  
}

const styles= StyleSheet.create({
    // Background Image Style
    container:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.lightWhite,
    },
    mediaContainer:{
        height:(height-marginTop) /1.9,
    },
    imageContainer:{
        width:"100%",
        height:"100%"
         
    },
    imageStyle:{
        height:"100%",
        width:"100%",
        borderRadius:20
    },

    // Profile Style
    profilePicBorderContainer:{
        flex:1,
        alignItems:'center'
    },
    profileImage:{
        height:155,
        width:155,
        borderRadius:999,
        borderColor:COLORS.green,
        borderWidth:2,
        marginTop:-90
    },
    iconImage:{
        position:"absolute",
        bottom:0,
        right:10,
        zIndex:9999
    },
    nameStyle:{
        ...FONTS.h3,
        color:COLORS.green,
        marginVertical:8,
    },
    titleStyle:{
        color:COLORS.black,
        ...FONTS.body4
    },
    locationStyle:{
        flexDirection:"row",
        marginVertical:6,
        alignItems:"center"
    },
    locationTextStyle:{
        ...FONTS.body4,
            marginLeft:4
        
    },
    // Card Styles
    activityCardContainer:{
        paddingVertical:8,
        flexDirection:"row"
    },
    activityCard:{
        flexDirection:"column",
        alignItems:"center",
        marginHorizontal:SIZES.padding
    },
    activityCardNumber:{
        ...FONTS.h2,
        color:COLORS.green
    },
    activityCardText:{
        ...FONTS.body4,
        color:COLORS.green
    },

    // Button Style 
    buttonContainer:{
        flexDirection:"row"
    },
    buttonPress:{
        width:124,
        height:36,
        alignItems:"center",
        justifyContent:"center",
        backgroundColor:COLORS.green,
        borderRadius:10,
        marginHorizontal:SIZES.padding*2,
    },
    buttonText:{
        ...FONTS.body4,
        color:COLORS.lightWhite
    },

    // Tab Nav Style
    tabNav:{
        flex:1,
        marginHorizontal:22,
        marginTop:20
    },
    scene: {
        flex: 1,
      },
      contentContainer: {
        flexGrow: 1,
      },


})
```